# Trying to find a best way of finding a word and printing that word and its value from JSON output using python

Tags: python, json

I have following JSON output and I need to find word "catid" and its value.
Any help/advice on doing so will be great.

```
json output: 
{
  "status": 200, 
  "type": "url", 
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.cnn.com", 
      "queries": {
        "getinfo": {
          "cats": [
            {
              "conf": 99, 
              "catid": 63
            }
          ], 
          "a1cat": -1, 
          "lcp": "cnn.com", 
          "reputation": -1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: there is a serious lack of shown effort but are you asking how to search the data for a key called "catid"? that is much different then understanding the `data["results"]` notation for getting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

json_string = '''{
  "status": 200, 
  "type": "url", 
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.cnn.com", 
      "queries": {
        "getinfo": {
          "cats": [
            {
              "conf": 99, 
              "catid": 63
            }
          ], 
          "a1cat": -1, 
          "lcp": "cnn.com", 
          "reputation": -1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}'''

data = json.loads(json_string)

print(data["results"][0]["queries"]["getinfo"]["cats"][0]["catid"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have parsed the json ouptu in json_ouput with `json.loads`

First catch `results` like this:

```
json_output["results"]
```

then catch the first element (since this is a list)

```
json_output["results"][0]
```

similarly go for `catid` like this:

```
json_output["results"][0]["queries"]["getinfo"]["cats"][0]["catid"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = result.get('results')
b= a[0]
c=b.get('queries').get('getinfo').get('cats')
for key,value in c[0].iteritems():
    print key,value
```